# Where to put reusable methods for access by controllers in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, architecture

I have several methods I call from my controllers that feel like they should be pulled out and put into a reusable class, outside of the controller. Where do people usually put this stuff? I know I can put them into my ApplicationController, but that doesn't seem to be a great solution if I think I can use these methods later in other applications.

Also, I have a bunch of utility methods in my controllers that likely won't be used in other controllers, or in the future at all, but I feel like they just bloat my controller a bit. Do people usually move these out someplace for cleanliness or just end up with a huge controller?

I'm coming from Java and Actionscript where I'd just create new util classes for this stuff.

Answer (score 14):

The lib directory is a place you can put modules/classes which can be mixed in or used by controllers (and anything else, really). This can be a place to put code that doesn't fall into other areas (but be careful about making sure lib doesn't turn into a mess itself). Side comments just to keep in mind:

- If you know you have a large amount of related functionality that could, or will, be used in other applications, that might be a plugin.
- Its also worth keeping in mind that there's nothing wrong with creating a model that is not an Active Record object. So again, depending on what you have, this might make sense as well.

Comment: Pete's two additional points are very good. I am of the opinion that `lib` is for "generic library" logic, not domain logic. Thus, if you have some logic that is specific to this application but common to several controllers, the right place might just be in a separate module in the `app/controllers` directory.

Answer (score 11):

Create a module file in `lib` directory:

```
module ControllerUtil
  def foo
  end

  def bar
  end
end
```

Include the module in the controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  include ControllerUtil
end
```

Answer (score 11):

You can create `app/modules` directory, and create XYZUtils module in it e.g

```
module XYZUtils
  def abc
  end

  def efg
  end
end
```

and include the module as and when required in Controllers or models etc.

```
include XYZUtils
```

You can create different modules for utility functions related to different Models or entities

I won't prefer `/lib` directory because that should contain the project related code, not app related, e.g tasks etc.

I would keep all the App related code in `/app` directory itself

Comment: Anyone liking this answer should also see @edebill's answer as for further good reasons why not to put such code in /lib

Answer (score 3):

Related to Sahil kalra's above answer from 2014:

Rails now has an `app/controllers/concerns` directory where you can put modules full of helper methods and easily include or extend them in your controllers.  I just copied and pasted all of my logic-intensive methods out of my application_controller and they worked right out of the box.

(You should, of course, still make sure everything works correctly before putting anything into production.)

Answer (score 1):

Controllers should be very minimal - basically ingesting arguments and making some very high level decisions.  If you have some helper functions that are doing just those kinds of things but aren't going to be reused, then keeping them in the controller is the right thing to do.  Just make sure to mark them as private.

For more commonly shared things, you can either back them into your ApplicationController (if they're used in all controllers) or into a class in your app/models directory.  I recommend the models directory over lib because Rails in development mode is much better about spotting changes to those files and reloading them.  Changes to files in /lib tend to require restarting the webserver, which slows down your development effort.  This is unfortunate, because controller helpers really should not be mixed with models.

In general, though, if you have more than a handful of these helpers, you're probably doing too much in your controllers.  Take a hard look at them and see if maybe some of them shouldn't be part of your models instead.